# When I create a new project in the latest version of android studio for 2020, it shows me this error

Tags: android

This is the error I get

```
   Gradle sync failed: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\k1\AndroidStudioProjects\Fixerror\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
                    No value with key 'distributionUrl' specified in wrapper properties file 'C:\Users\k1\AndroidStudioProjects\Fixerror\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (96 ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` there should be a value for `distributionUrl` for example

```
#Wed May 27 16:03:33 BST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

**EDIT**

You can file the file here
[image]

Comment: I dont found this file

Comment: I have updated my answer